# Traveling abroad on Advance Parole

Tags: usa, greencard

I am traveling pretty soon on my Advance Parole, which is a combo card with my employment authorization document (EAD), and it does not expire until September 20, 2016. My travel dates are between July 2 and July 19.

While leaving the United States, do I have to find an immigration officer or someone to look at my AP and have them stamp or approve my travel? How does this work? What are the steps I would need to take, and how do I make sure that I would have no problems getting back into the United States?

I have a legit job and no criminal history. I will be taking my EAD card with me.

Comment: The advance parole *is* prior approval of your travel. Why would you think you need an additional stamp?

Comment: So that means I can just travel worry free and the only time I would need to show my AP is while I re-enter the united states right?

Comment: You might have to show your AP in some other contexts. For example, if you would otherwise need a transit visa in the UK, there are several US documents that can exempt you from that requirement, and IIRC the AP is such a document. You might need to show it to the airline when you leave. But aside from information gathered indirectly (such as by the airlines), the US has no exit controls.

Answer (score 2):

Advance Parole means you already have approval to leave the United States and return without abandoning your application to adjust status.

You only need to carry the card with you.

You don't need to present the card when *leaving* the United States.

You *do* need to present the card when *returning* to the United States. You must present it to the airline at check-in, so that they know that you are authorized to travel to the United States. You must also present it to a CBP officer at immigration when you arrive back in the United States.